# MySQL subquery unknown column for complex query

Tags: mysql

I've got the following sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/324628/1

I need to create a query that returns the id and the position (ranking) of each student within his class; the position is sorted in descending order according to the value of their academic average stored inside the `academic_averages` table.

(e.g. the first from class 1, second from the class 1, and so on... the first from class 2, the second from class 2...)

Here's the query:

```
SELECT students.id,

(SELECT x.position
FROM (
    SELECT t.student_id, t.value, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position
    FROM (
        SELECT aa.student_id, aa.value
        FROM academic_averages AS aa
        INNER JOIN students AS s ON s.id = aa.student_id
        INNER JOIN classes_students AS cs ON cs.student_id = s.id
        INNER JOIN classes_academic_years AS cas ON cas.id = cs.class_academic_year_id

        INNER JOIN classes_academic_years as cas2 on cas2.class_id = cas.class_id
        INNER JOIN classes_students as cs2 on cs2.class_academic_year_id = cas2.id
        INNER JOIN students as s2 on s2.id = cs2.student_id

        WHERE s2.id = 243
        AND cas.academic_year_id = 4
        AND aa.academic_year_id = 4

        GROUP BY aa.student_id
        ORDER BY abs(aa.value) DESC
    ) t 
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
) AS x WHERE x.student_id = students.id ) AS ranking_by_class

FROM students
```

However, since it contains a subquery, I cannot change the WHERE from the inner most query to `s2.id = students.id` because it throws an error (unknown column).

I've tried using an INNER JOIN instead of subqueries, but no luck so far.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

LE: Performance wise the query must be optimized

LE: Here's the structure of the tables:

**academic_averages**:

```
id
student_id
value
academic_year_id
```

**classes_academic_years**:

```
id
class_id
name
grade
academic_year_id
```

**classes_students**:

```
id
class_academic_year_id
student_id
```

**classes**:

```
id
school_id
```

**students**:

```
id
```

The desired output should be `student_id, position`.
There seems to be some issues with sql fiddle, meanwhile here's the schema: http://snippi.com/s/db8za8k

Comment: the sqlfiddle is blank for me. please post the schema of the relevant tables.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused about the desired output format. do you want the result set to be `(year, class_id, student_id, position)`?

Comment: @HaleemurAli I've edited my question to include the db structure and the desired output structure. I've also added the schema since sql fiddle seems to be having some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.id
  , x.position
  , x.academic_average
FROM (SELECT
  s.id
  , @rownum := @rownum + 1 position
  , av.value academic_average
FROM students s
JOIN classes_students cs ON s.id = cs.student_id 
JOIN classes_academic_years cay ON cay.id = cs.class_academic_year_id
JOIN academic_averages av ON av.student_id = s.id
WHERE cay.academic_year_id = 4 -- change these two parameters in    
  AND  av.academic_year_id = 4 -- the subquery for different years
ORDER BY av.value DESC) x,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) y
ORDER BY academic_average DESC
```

I think the above query should work for you.

I've made the assumption that the academic ranking `position` is determined in a descending order by academic average.

I don't have access to your dataset, so I've added three extra lines, two to select the students' academic average and one to order the result in descending order according to the academic average. This should help you verify that it works as intended. If you run the query, and it works, it should display records with `position` starting at 1 and incrementing by 1.

In production I would omit these fragments in order to get the result set you specify:
1. `, x.academic_average`
2. `, av.value academic_average`
3. `ORDER BY academic_average DESC`

### Edit following elaboration in comments by OP *(students' ranking required by class)*

This query should give you students' positions by class. If you want to get rid of some fields, you can wrap the `SELECT` in another `SELECT`, or ignore the columns once the dataset is extracted to another language.

```
SELECT 
    x.student_id
  , x.cay_class_id
  , x.academic_average
  , if(@classid = x.cay_class_id, @rownum := @rownum + 1, @rownum := 1) position
  , @classid := x.cay_class_id
FROM (SELECT
    s.id student_id
  , cay.class_id cay_class_id
  , av.value academic_average

FROM students s
JOIN classes_students cs ON s.id = cs.student_id 
JOIN classes_academic_years cay ON cay.id = cs.class_academic_year_id
JOIN academic_averages av ON av.student_id = s.id
WHERE cay.academic_year_id = 4 -- change these two parameters in    
  AND  av.academic_year_id = 4 -- the subquery for different years
ORDER BY cay.class_id, av.value DESC) x,
(SELECT @classid := 0, @rownum := 0) y
```

Comment: It's not working properly. Here's the sqlfiddle for my attempt (which is working properly for a single class) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/324628/1 and here is your example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/324628/2

Comment: The position is determined in an descending order by the academic average, that assumption is correct, however, it's based on each student's class, (e.g. the first from class 1, second from the class 1, and so on... the first from class 2, the second from class 2...)